# Stabilization of von Neumann equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

Given the solution of the von Neumann equation 
$\rho(t) = e^{-i H t/\hbar} \rho(0) e^{i H t/\hbar}$

How can we justify if it will be stabilized as $t\rightarrow\infty$ in general?

For example, consider $H=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \\
\ \rho(0)=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$

Is possible to fix for this case? Also, is it normal? Shouldn't there be some wave dynamics before reaching equilibrium?

Answer (score 1):

A density matrix will never *approach* a steady state under purely unitary evolution. It is possible for the density matrix to be *initialised* in a steady state, if this state is already diagonal in the energy representation. That is, if the initial state satisfies $[H,\rho(0)]=0$ then the density matrix does not evolve, as in the OP's example. Otherwise, there will always be coherent oscillations. One can see this by examining the condition that the derivative of the density matrix be zero at some point in time:
$$ \dot{\rho}(t) = -i[H,\rho(t)] = -i[H,e^{-iHt}\rho(0)e^{iHt}] = -i e^{-iHt}[H,\rho(0)]e^{iHt} = 0.$$
This shows that if $\dot{\rho}(t)=0$ at any time, then the initial density matrix satisfies $[H,\rho(0)]$, which implies that $\dot{\rho}(t) = 0$ at every time.

Assuming that $\dot{\rho}(t)\neq 0$, one can expand the density matrix in eigenstates $\lvert n\rangle$ of the Hamiltonian satisfying $H|n\rangle = E_n|n\rangle$:
$$ \rho(t) = \sum_{m,n} \rho_{mn}(0) e^{-iHt}\lvert m\rangle\langle n\rvert e^{-iHt} = \sum_{m,n} \rho_{mn}(0) e^{-i(E_m-E_n)t}\lvert m\rangle\langle n\rvert = \sum_{m,n} \rho_{mn}(t) \lvert m\rangle\langle n\rvert,$$
where $\rho_{mn}(t)$ are the matrix elements at time $t$. Therefore, the *populations* $\rho_{nn}(t) = \rho_{nn}(0)$ stay the same while the *coherences* $\rho_{mn}(t)$ oscillate at the frequency $E_m-E_n$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But I am not very sure where it was used the condition $[H, \rho(0)]\neq 0$ to prove that the solution $\rho(t)$ will be stabilized, where it is not related to the zero derivative, since there can be small fluctuation even with large derivative.

Comment: Hi @XingdongZuo, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "stabilised". Do you mean reaching thermal equilibrium?

Comment: Yes, and in the solution function graph the fluctuation of the curve to be smaller and smaller as time to infinity. The point is not against the proof with the eigenstates, but the place where we can use the condition that $H$ and $\rho(0)$ does not commutes, since the the form above can always be shown even if $[H, \rho(0)]=0$

Comment: @XingdongZuo But the state of a system *does not* reach thermal equilibrium as $t\to 0$ under unitary evolution. If $[\rho,H]\neq 0$ you will just see coherent oscillations forever. There is no damping of fluctuations without some external influence.

Comment: I agree with it that for the closed quantum system it will endlessly oscillate. Well, I'd like to know if it is possible to explicitly to show $[H, \rho(0)]\neq 0$ in your proof of the form of expansion of density operator above, i.e. $$ \rho(t) = \sum_{m,n} \rho_{mn}(0) e^{-iHt}\lvert m\rangle\langle n\rvert e^{-iHt} = \sum_{m,n} \rho_{mn}(0) e^{-i(E_m-E_n)t}\lvert m\rangle\langle n\rvert = \sum_{m,n} \rho_{mn}(t) \lvert m\rangle\langle n\rvert,$$

Comment: @XingdongZuo This expansion holds whether or not $[H,\rho(0)] = 0$. However, $[H,\rho(0)] = 0$ implies that $\rho_{mn} = 0$ for $E_m\neq E_n$, and therefore there are no oscillations. That is, if $[H,\rho(0)]=0$, it follows that $\rho_{mn}(t) = \rho_{mn}(0)e^{i(E_m-E_n)t} = \rho_{mn}(0)$, since either $e^{i(E_m-E_n)t}=1$ or $\rho_{mn}(0) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand. By the way, is it called stationary state in physics ?

Comment: @XingdongZuo You're welcome. Yes, a probability distribution that does not evolve in time can be called a stationary state or steady state in physics.